# I'd like to clear objects that no longer exist from a collection, can this be done with python?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I keep getting this error when iterating through objects in collection.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Note that the object has been deleted. Or is it because it's 2.81 beta?

Comment: You're trying to select and object that is no longer part of the view layer. You need to check whether the object is still in the view layer. What you need to do depends on how you decide what is going to be selected.

Comment: not sure how to check an object that is no longer there.. maybe if I check the objects that do exist & cancel out the ones that dont

Comment: If you add the section of code whee the problem occurs to your question we may be able to help with that..